# Get value from exist key array php

Tags: php, arrays

Which method can I use to get the value from the exist key?

```
<?php
$account = array (
    'john' => '1234',
    'bert' => '5678',
);


if(array_key_exists("john", $account)){
// get the value 1234
}
?>
```

Comment: The key is the index so use it in the `[]`s. e.g. `$account['john']` although that doesn't seem like a good key.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)